# How to pass options from PyTest to Twisted.trial?

Tags: python, pytest, twisted

I have some twisted.trial tests in my project, that is tests inheriting from twisted.trial.unittest.TestCase.

I need to pass some trial options to my test, specifically it is --reactor option of twisted.trial command line utility. Is there some way for me to pass it to pytest? My thinking is: I add something to pytest.ini, and pytest would somehow launch my trial unittest testcase with this option. Is that possible at the moment?

Sample to reproduce this. Take the following unit test:

```py
# test_reactor.py
from twisted.trial.unittest import TestCase


class CrawlTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_if_correct_reactor(self):
        from twisted.internet import reactor
        from twisted.internet.asyncioreactor import AsyncioSelectorReactor
        assert isinstance(reactor, AsyncioSelectorReactor)
```

Now run it with trial with --reactor flag

```
python -m twisted.trial --reactor=asyncio test_reactor
test_reactor
  CrawlTestCase
    test_if_correct_reactor ...                                            [OK]

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 tests in 0.042s

PASSED (successes=1)
```

Now run it without --reactor flag

```
python -m twisted.trial test_reactor
test_reactor
  CrawlTestCase
    test_if_correct_reactor ...                                         [ERROR]

===============================================================================
[ERROR]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pawel/.../test_reactor.py", line 8, in test_if_correct_reactor
    assert isinstance(reactor, AsyncioSelectorReactor)
builtins.AssertionError: 

test_reactor.CrawlTestCase.test_if_correct_reactor
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 tests in 0.081s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Now run it with pytest

```
py.test test_reactor.py
============================================================================================================ test session starts =============================================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.4, pytest-6.2.3, py-1.11.0, pluggy-0.13.1
benchmark: 3.4.1 (defaults: timer=time.perf_counter disable_gc=False min_rounds=5 min_time=0.000005 max_time=1.0 calibration_precision=10 warmup=False warmup_iterations=100000)
rootdir: /home/pawel/../aaomw, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: Faker-8.1.3, hypothesis-6.10.1, benchmark-3.4.1
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

test_reactor.py F
```

Question is: how do I pass something to pytest so that it passes it to trial? Is there something I can put in pytest.ini so that reactor is passed to twisted trial?

If what I'm trying to do is not possible, please provide proof that it is not possible, this is also possibly accepted answer, perhaps something needs to be changed in pytest to make this kind of thing possible.

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption is what you want and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63385942/6817835) shows just that

Comment: I can add option but I don't see it is actually passed to twisted.trial? Have you tested this approach with this specific flag? I'm not asking about any possible pytest option, I know how to add pytest options, it's about pytest options for twisted.trial.

Answer (score 0):

After installing [pytest-twisted](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-twisted/) plugin I get --reactor flag and a proper option of installing and launching reactor.